# SFINAE Member Pass through

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I was wondering if it was possible to create a class that would serve as a combination between std::enable_if and a SFINAE member detector.

```
class foo
{
public:
    int bar;
};

template <class T>
typename enable_if_has_bar<T>::type ReturnBar (const T& value)
{
    return value.bar;
}
```

So I attempted to do this.

```
class foo
{
public:
    int bar;
};

template <class C, C>
class Check;

template <class T, class Enable = void>
class enable_if_has_bar
{};

template <class T>
class enable_if_has_bar<T, Check <decltype(&T::bar),&T::bar>>
{
public:
    typedef decltype(static_cast<T*>(0)->*static_cast<decltype(&T::bar)>(0)) type;
};

template <class T>
typename enable_if_has_bar<T>::type ReturnBar (const T& value)
{
    return value.bar;
}

int main ()
{
    foo foobar;
    foobar.bar = 42;

    cout << ReturnBar(foobar) << endl;
}
```

( http://ideone.com/WKTfmQ )

It doesn't seem to work, and I'm not quite as versed in the fine art of SFINAE as I could be. Perhaps someone could improve/fix it? Because I'm at a loss.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ReturnBar(foobar)`, and `&T::bar`? Not that it works even then, but it would be closer to working.

Comment: Oy, quite the typo there. Thanks

Comment: Funny little joke: I pronounce SFINAE "SNIFNAE" (yes with two n's) so it sounds like "SNIF-NAY". He-he

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally prefer to create custom `enable_if`-style types as you've attempted, because I find the code clearer to read with a single trait type, rather than a combination of `enable_if<some_trait<T>, another_trait<T>>`. But in this case there are a few problems in your code stopping it working.

Your `enable_if_has_bar` specialization will never be selected, the return type of `ReturnBar` just instantiates the primary template, `enable_if_has_bar<foo, void>`, and that never defines the nested `type`.  Nothing causes the specialization to be instantiated so there is nothing that checks whether `T::bar` is a valid expression.

Your `decltype(static_cast<T*>(0)->*static_cast<decltype(&T::bar)>(0))` expression will result in `int&` not `int` as you probably want.  This is because `decltype(foobar.*(&foo::bar))` is equivalent to `decltype(foobar.bar)` and `foobar.bar` is an lvalue, so the `decltype` is `int&`.  The function `ReturnBar` would fail to compile if it returns `int&` because the parameter `value` is const, so you can't bind `value.bar` to a non-const `int&`.

Here's a working version:

```
template <class T>
  class has_bar
  {
    template<typename U, typename = decltype(&U::bar)>
      static std::true_type
      test(U*);

    static std::false_type
    test(...);

  public:
    static const int value = decltype(test((T*)nullptr))::value;
  };

template<typename T, bool = has_bar<T>::value>
  struct enable_if_has_bar
  { };

template<typename T>
  struct enable_if_has_bar<T, true>
  : std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T&>().*(&T::bar))>
  { };
```

This first declares the helper `has_bar` to answer the question of whether the type has the nested member. That helper uses SFINAE to get a `true` or `false` value. If `&T::bar` is a valid expression then the first overload of `test` will be used, which returns `true_type` and so `value` will be set to `true_type::value` i.e. `true`. Otherwise the fallback overload will be selected and `value` set to `false`.

Then the `enable_if_has_bar` template uses a default template parameter which is deduced as the value of `has_bar<T>::value`. The primary template is used when `has_bar<T>::value` is false. The specialization is used when `has_bar<T>::value` is true, in which case we know the expression `&T::bar` is valid and can use it in a decltype expression to get the type.

`std::decay` is used to turn the `int&` result of the decltype expression to just `int`. Inheriting from `decay` is a bit shorter than using it to define the member, which would be:

```
typedef typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T&>().*(&T::bar))>::type type;
```

I used the standard utility `declval<T>()` in the unevaluated expressions, which is a bit shorter to type and a bit more idiomatic and expressive than `static_cast<T*>(0)`.

An alternative to using `decay` would be another helper type to get the type `int` from the type `int T::*` e.g.

```
template<typename T>
  struct remove_class;
  { };

template<typename Member, typename Class>
  struct remove_class<Member Class::*>
  {
    typedef Member type;
  };

template<typename T>
  struct enable_if_has_bar<T, true>
  : remove_class<decltype(&T::bar)>
  { };
```

(The name `remove_class` isn't very good, but basically it takes a pointer-to-data-member type and gives the type of the member.)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, sorry. I've edited my answer to be clear which decltype expression I was referring to, does that help?

Comment: Why are we doing `std::declval<T&>` instead of `std::declval<T>`. Isn't it *supposed* to return `T&`?

Comment: @David, in `declval<T&>()` the `T` is the class type, not the type we want to return. Using `declval<T>().*(&T::bar)` would result in `int&&` which is still not helpful. The `ReturnBar` function has a parameter of type `const T&`, so `return value.bar;` is a `const int&` which cannot bind to a return type of `int&` or `int&&`. Try it.

Comment: If the intention is for `ReturnBar` to return a reference to the member then it could return `const enable_if_has_bar<T>::type&` instead, which would work. `ReturnBar` could be adapted to use perfect forwarding, and return the member as the right value category (rvalue or lvalue) but that would be a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

Although Jonathan Wakely's answer is very good let me offer a slightly different pattern:

```
//this goes in some header so you can use it everywhere
template<typename T>
struct TypeSink{
    using Type = void;
};
template<typename T>
using TypeSinkT = typename TypeSink<T>::Type;

//here is the use case
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct enable_if_has_bar{ };

template<typename T>
struct enable_if_has_bar<T, TypeSinkT<decltype(std::declval<T&>().*(&T::bar))>>
  : std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T&>().*(&T::bar))>
  { };
```

Here is a live example: http://ideone.com/un0ZgH

Although it is naturally a question of taste I like using the type sink pattern because the syntax for the SFINAE test and the syntax I am actually using in the metafunction body is exactly the same and right next to each other. It is therefore hopefully less bug prone.